# What is the best way to preseve old equipment without fungus and moisture?

Tags: equipment-protection, fungus

I am building a rather sizable equipment list, Leicas and Olys, plus their lenses.

The thing I that I want to keep them moisture and fungus free. I saw somewhere that Ziploc bags and silica packs are not enough.

What techniques can I use that will prevent fungus and moisture buildup in both lenses and equipment?

thanks

Comment: Haven't tried these myself, but I guess you're looking for a [dry box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dry_box) - either an airtight enclosure with silica gel, or an electronic dry cabinet like [these](http://www.digihub.com.sg/index.php?route=product/product&path=20_26&product_id=52).

Comment: Oh wow, that looks fancy AND expensive. :) But I guess it is the correct way if I am already spending enough money in vintage cameras.

Comment: Seems to be from $100 and up in Singapore: http://www.harveynorman.com.sg/digital-cameras/camera-accessories/dry-cabinets.html Not all that much compared to the cost of a Leica :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While more expensive and bulky than plastic bags and silica packs, you might consider Pelican cases or equivalent.  I have a couple of Pelican cases which I use for travel, including checking my equipment through as baggage. The reason I went for the Pelican case is that it is completely sealed and waterproof.

That said, I'm not sure that it will prevent the moisture in the air from being in there, and therefore might not provide the level of protection you're looking for.

I'm curious as to your environment and what leads you to worry about moisture and fungus damaging your equipment.

Comment: For the most part of the year the entire house is closed, with little to no "proper" air circulation. Fungus is a problem even within the walls where I live, so. :)